# What is known about the Hurrian "wa" compound signs?

Tags: cuneiform, hittite, hurrian

According to the classic *Hethitisches Zeichenlexikon*, Hurrian used a handful of special signs made by combining the WA (aka PI) sign with others: *wa+ap*, *wa+i*, *wa+pí*, *wa+ú*, *wa+e*, *wa+u*, *wa+pu*, *wa+ip*, *wa+a*. (HZL transliterates them *u̯a<sub>ap</sub>* etc.)

The authors have this to say about those (p253, my translation):

> For the sign *u̯a<sub>a</sub>* appearing in Proto-Hattic, Hurrian, and Palaic word-forms and texts, only the traditional transliteration is given here. Due to the still-uncertain state of the art, a phonetic/phonological interpretation (like *fa*<sup>?</sup>) is avoided. […] Palaic spellings of this sort likely come from Proto-Hattic influence […] The exact Lautwert must be determined in individual languages.

But this was published in 1989, and I haven't been able to find any more modern discussion of these signs. Has any consensus been reached since then? (And as a side note, what is this "Proto-Hattic" (*protohattischen*) they're talking about?)

Comment: (For completeness, I should note that Wilhelm does mention the ones with vowel signs in passing, saying they represent _fa_, _fe_, etc, but doesn't mention the ones with _pí_, _ip_, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Protohattisch* is perhaps the [Hattic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hattic_language), the isolated languages which had been spoken on the territory of the Hittite kingdom before Hittites arrived and settled there. The language is known from toponyms and a very scarce corpus written in syllabic cuneiform which makes it decipherment still more problematic. Hittites used Hattic as a ritual language in the cults of some gods, and no historical stages (Proto-Hattic vs. Hattic proper) can be distinguished. Sometimes Hattic was called Proto-Hittite actually meaning ‘Pre-Hittite’, maybe “Protohethitisch” was simply misspelled as “Protohattish”. Generally speaking, there's a traditional confusion of the words ‘Hattic’ and ‘Hittite’, even the capital of the Hittite kingdom was called Hattusas.

As for the *WA* (PI) sign, it is discussed in detail on pages 21–23 of this book:
[An Introduction to the Hurrian Language [2020, Ilse Wegner (Revised, edited, and reformatted by Allan R. Bomhard)]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rpkXvObkUG6UCiiCaiCSNQm8X12tENAZ/view?usp=sharing) (downloadable, 1Mb). Since it's more than 2 pages of text, I cannot cite it all here, besides you'll probably know it better which is of greater relevance for you there. What I understood is WA (IP) was used for writing consonants *w*/*f*, and the vowel was determined by the sign that followed, the *a* of WA wasn't taken into account.

Comment: Many thanks! One thing I might add to the answer (based on that book): they say the meanings of wa+ap, wa+ip, wa+pu are still uncertain, but Thiel/Wegner suggest wa+ap = _af(f)_. But this source answers my question completely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Hurrian scribes wanted to remove some of the inherent ambiguity of the cuneiform signs.
It can be noted that signs like gi+e also exist.
The sign PI = wa is extremely ambiguous and can be read pi, wa, we, wi, wu, which obviously is troublesome.
Personally, I don't believe in the theory that Hurrian had sounds like f or v. For example the word "mountain" *pabani has an equivalent as Urartian baban. Besides, Kurdish has a word bane "mountain". None of these words has f or v. Not to mention also Ancient Greek bounos.

Comment: Fair enough, but what about signs like wa+pu and wa+ip? Given that afaict Hurrian never distinguished P from B, and Hittite never used that sign for /pi/, I'd be surprised if it was that.